# Is there a browser library for using the Chrome Debugging Protocol/API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Chrome provides a nice [remote debugging API](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/debugger-protocol), which is useful in many scenarios.

I've found a nice and rich client library for using it from a Node.js server environment: https://github.com/cyrus-and/chrome-remote-interface - this works great from a server connecting to the browser.

Is there a similar library that can be used from within the browser itself? So either from one browser instance to another browser instance that's started in debug mode, or to the same browser instance? I know that one could do that with some fiddling with a WS library etc., but I would like to avoid the low-level work if possible. The above server library does a great job of abstracting away most of that. Is there something comparable for JavaScript running in the browser?

Comment: You mean a library to instrumentalize, not just the devtools client?

Comment: Yes, exactly. A library that I could put into my web app using something like Bower. I'll change the title of the question to make it clear what I'm looking for.

Comment: Have you tried [browserifying](http://browserify.org/) that library? What happens [in there](https://github.com/cyrus-and/chrome-remote-interface/blob/master/lib/chrome.js) is no magic, you might only need to adapt the websocket parts. And you will need to start your browser with SOP disabled to make the websockets work…

Comment: Yes, I thought about that. I just wanted to check before I start that whether there's anything out there that I could use out of the box.

Comment: Do you know that the UI part of the DevTools is actually a page that uses the same protocol and can work as a remote client? So you can run one browser with enabled remote debugging port 9222 and open the url http://localhost:9222 in another browser instance. See https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/debugger-protocol

Answer (score 0):

Check out [weinre](http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/) (WEb INspector REmote)